# error with color mapping in two graphs with common legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am trying to make a graph using ggarrange and a common legend.
However the color scheme and legend is only correct for the first graph.

If you look at the graph I know that the large yellow bar on the right is Lactococcus however the color to level mapping is different between the two graphs (Lactococcus is light green in legend as per left graph). I thought I took care of this by reordering the levels.

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong or there is a better way to do this.  thanks

```
 dat.czm.annot<-merge(dat.czm,metadata,by.x="row.names",by.y="SampleID")
  ##
  dat.czm.annot.Ab<-subset(dat.czm.annot,Antibiotics=="Antibiotics")
  ##
  dat.czm.annot.NoAb<-subset(dat.czm.annot,Antibiotics=="None")
  ## before separating Ab and NoAb find totals and overall top10    
    dat.grouped<-dat.czm.annot %>%
        group_by(Diet,Time) %>%
        summarise_at(vars(colnames(dat.czm)), funs(mean(., na.rm=TRUE)))
      dat.groupedM<-melt(dat.grouped)
      dat.groupedM<-subset(dat.groupedM,Diet != "Control")
      dat.groupedM$Level<-as.factor(as.character(tax_tab1[match(dat.groupedM$variable,rownames(tax_tab1)),ncol(tax_tab1)]))
      ##
      dat.grouped.Ab<-dat.czm.annot.Ab %>%
        group_by(Diet,Time) %>%
        summarise_at(vars(colnames(dat.czm)), funs(mean(., na.rm=TRUE)))
      dat.groupedM.Ab<-melt(dat.grouped.Ab)
      dat.groupedM.Ab<-subset(dat.groupedM.Ab,Diet != "Control")
      dat.groupedM.Ab$Level<-as.factor(as.character(tax_tab1[match(dat.groupedM.Ab$variable,rownames(tax_tab1)),ncol(tax_tab1)]))
      ###
      dat.grouped.NoAb<-dat.czm.annot.NoAb %>%
        group_by(Diet,Time) %>%
        summarise_at(vars(colnames(dat.czm)), funs(mean(., na.rm=TRUE)))
      dat.groupedM.NoAb<-melt(dat.grouped.NoAb)
      dat.groupedM.NoAb<-subset(dat.groupedM.NoAb,Diet != "Control")
      dat.groupedM.NoAb$Level<-as.factor(as.character(tax_tab1[match(dat.groupedM.NoAb$variable,rownames(tax_tab1)),ncol(tax_tab1)]))
      ##
      meanAbund<-as.data.frame(colSums(dat.grouped[,grep("Otu",colnames(dat.grouped))]))
      meanAbund$Name<-as.character(tax_tab1[match(rownames(meanAbund),rownames(tax_tab1)),ncol(tax_tab1)])
      colnames(meanAbund)<-c("mean_abund","Name")
      top10_meanAbund<-meanAbund[rev(order(meanAbund$mean_abund))[1:10],]
      top10Names<-top10_meanAbund$Name
      ## used melted dataframe for plotting
      ## now ordered by mean abundance
      dat.groupedM.Ab$Level<-factor(dat.groupedM.Ab$Level,meanAbund[rev(order(meanAbund$mean_abund)),"Name"])
      dat.groupedM.NoAb$Level<-factor(dat.groupedM.NoAb$Level,meanAbund[rev(order(meanAbund$mean_abund)),"Name"])
      library(RColorBrewer)
      n <- length(unique(dat.groupedM$Level))
      qual_col_pals = brewer.pal.info[brewer.pal.info$category == 'qual',]
      col_vector = unlist(mapply(brewer.pal, qual_col_pals$maxcolors, rownames(qual_col_pals)))
      set.seed(200)
      mycols<-sample(col_vector, n)
      ##
      PlotAb<-ggplot(dat.groupedM.Ab, aes(x = Time, y = value, fill = Level)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        facet_wrap(~Diet)+
        scale_fill_manual(values = mycols,breaks=top10Names) +
        theme_bw()+
       # labs(fill="top 10 genera")+
        ggtitle("Cohort 2 Antibiotics")
      ## used melted dataframe for plotting
      ## now ordered by mean abundance
      ##
      PlotNoAb<-ggplot(dat.groupedM.NoAb, aes(x = Time, y = value, fill = Level)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        facet_wrap(~Diet)+
        scale_fill_manual(values = mycols,breaks=top10Names) +
        theme_bw()+
        #labs(fill="top 10 genera")+
        ggtitle("Cohort 2 No Antibiotics")
      ggarrange(PlotNoAb,PlotAb,ncol=2,nrow=1,common.legend = T,legend="bottom")
```

[image]

I know this isn't reproducible.  I tried to make a test subset, but I'm having problems with that.  Hopefully someone can 'read' my script and understand what my problem is.

thanks

Comment: It would probably be easier to `rbind` the two data frames and facet by two variables.

Comment: Are you sure Lactococcus is coded as green in the legend?  I believe `ggplot2` puts the color to the left of the label, meaning the green is actually Bacteroides.  Note that there's no yellow key at all; it may be cut off on the far left.

Comment: A reproducible example, such as a reprex (https://community.rstudio.com/t/faq-whats-a-reproducible-example-reprex-and-how-do-i-do-one/5219][1]) attracts a lot more answers. Can you reproduce the problem with a standard dataset? That vastly simplifies the skull sweat required to pinpoint the problem for the much larger help pool than the premier league players.


  [1]: https://community.rstudio.com/t/faq-whats-a-reproducible-example-reprex-and-how-do-i-do-one/5219